# Reading information from text files, line by line

Tags: c, file-io

I want to learn how to read `.txt` files in `C`, line by line so that the information in each line can be used in loops etc. I don't have a homework exercise for this but I need to figure it out for a project to write a script for an astronomy package.

So in order to learn how to do this I created a file called `list.txt` with the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 each on separate lines and I want the program to sum the values on each line. I also created an output file called `sum.txt` and the program is supposed to sum the lines, and print the sum to the output file.

I am getting an error when I run the program and I'm not sure what the problem is as I don't fully understand this. I got this program in a book on C and tried to modify it to run it on my PC.

The reason I need to be able to do this is because I need to take information from each line in a list (each line containing one string). But I want to learn to do it with numbers first.

Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, sum = 0;
    FILE *ifp, *ofp;
    ifp = fopen("list.txt", "r");
    ofp = ("sum.txt", "w");
    while (fscanf(ifp, "%d", &a) == 1)
    {
        sum += a;
        fprintf(ofp, "The sum is %d. \n", sum);
        fclose(ifp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? also, I note that you never close `ofp`

Comment: If you get an error, then please share what the error message is.

Comment: "expression (stream != NULL)" is the message im getting. Sorry i should have noted that it does compile, but when i try to debug it fails

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to write `fopen` here:

```
ofp = ("sum.txt", "w");
```

Also, you should move the `fclose` (and possibly the `fprintf`) out of the while loop, since you only want to close the file after reading all the lines.

Comment: @LauraBoyle: Your fopen on input file might be failing. Make sure the file list.txt is in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: @codaddict: That's it! thank you! It wasn't that I had it in the wrong directory, I had saved it as (list.txt).txt

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the input file after the loop and move the `fprintf` outside the loop too:

```
} // end of while loop
fprintf(ofp, "The sum is %d. \n", sum);
fclose(ifp);
```

Also don't forget to do error checking and ensure that you've opened the files before you go on and to IO on them.